# Can't install PDQ tool for R on windows

Tags: windows, r, installation, modeling, capacity-planning

I've been trying for half an hour following this simple guide http://www.perfdynamics.com/Tools/PDQcode.html#tth_sEc1.1.1

It simply throws this error:

```
> install.packages("C:\\Users\\Neven\\Downloads\\pdq_6.0-1.tar.gz",repos=NULL,type="source")

Warning: invalid package 'C:/Users/Neven/Downloads/pdq_6.0-1.tar.gz'
Error: ERROR: no packages specified
Warning messages:
1: running command '"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-30~1.2/bin/x64/R" CMD INSTALL -l "C:\ProgramFiles\R\R-3.0.2\library" "C:/Users/Neven/Downloads/pdq_6.0-1.tar.gz"' had status 1 
2: In install.packages("C:\\Users\\Neven\\Downloads\\pdq_6.0-1.tar.gz",  :
installation of package ‘C:/Users/Neven/Downloads/pdq_6.0-1.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status
```

I've been searching for an answer on the website, trying different things but nothing did it.

Comment: Do you have RTools installed?

Comment: Yes I installed them after R. I was surprised they were installed in the location different than R. Was that a problem maybe?

Comment: No - they shouldn't be in the same location as R typically.  Is RTools on your path?  I know there is an option to add it to the path during the RTools installation but I don't remember if it defaults to adding itself to the path or not.  I've known some people to have problems because even though they installed RTools it wasn't added to the path.

Comment: It couldn't hurt to post the output of `sessionInfo()` and `Sys.getenv("PATH")`

Comment: Here you go:
sessionInfo(): http://pastebin.com/v21JhsM3
Sys.getenv("PATH"): http://pastebin.com/kaHVxyZE

I see at the output of Sys.getenv("PATH") the first path is to RTools so I guess the env variable is set?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was copy/pasting the command from their documentation and it seems their documentation is out of date.

The command is:

```
install.packages("C:\\Users\\Neven\\Downloads\\pdq_6.0-1.tar.gz",repos=NULL,type="source")
```

Since there's a new version of R (6.1-1), it should be:

```
install.packages("C:\\Users\\Neven\\Downloads\\pdq_6.1-1.tar.gz",repos=NULL,type="source")
```

Really stupid mistake, but that's what solved the problem.